# Retrieve data from three entities where two of them are in many-to-one relationships with the last one

Tags: json, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql, many-to-one

I am using Spring Boot as REST backend app. Let's say that Person has Cats and Dogs and both Cat and Dog are in many-to-one relathionships with Person. By this, Cat and Dog have Person id as a foreign key. Since I'm using Spring JPA Repository and many-to-one relationship, it is straightforward to get list of cats with their persons and list of dogs with their persons. Those lists are transformed to json and I can access the person's data with frontend app. Here is my problem:
**I want to return the list of all persons with all the cats and dogs for each person.**
I guess that JPA Repository does not have a default query for my request, so I have to use custom queries. However, I do not know how to make it. I have tried the following one:

```
@Query("select p, c, d from Person p, Cat c, Dog d where c.person.id = :id and d.person.id = :id and person.id = :id")  
List<Object[]> findAllPersonsWithCatsAndDogs(Integer id);
```

The idea was to run through for loop for each person and to use person's id to retrieve his cats and dogs. The result is the list of objects where each object has the same person, one of his cats, and one of his dogs. I do not like that, because then for all persons I have a list of lists of persons with their cats and dogs.
How to get **one** list of all persons with all the cats and dogs for each person.
Thanks
Here are the mappings to make it more clear:

```
@Entity  
public class Person {  
//there is no mappings because of unidirectional many to one  
}
...  
@Entity  
public class Cat{  
        @ManyToOne  
        @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
        private Person person;  
}  
...  
@Entity  
public class Dog{  
        @ManyToOne    
        @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")  
        private Person person;  
}
```

So, I have many to one unidirectional, which means that Person does not see cats and dogs.

Comment: Can you show your entity mapping java class?

Comment: Yes, I added them to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the reference between person, cat and dog.

```
@Entity  
public class Person {  
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy="person")
  private List<Cat> catList;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy="person")
  private List<Dog> dogList; 
}
```

Then if you want to get all the people with their cats and dogs you can do something like

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Person P JOIN FETCH p.catList JOIN FETCH p.dogList")
List<Person> findAllPersonsWithCatsAndDogs()
```

(`catList` and `dogList` are just assumed to be the list in person due to not seeing your mapping).

This query will eager fetch your cats and dog list for every person. Then you can do

```
for (Person p : personRepo.findAllPersonsWithCatsAndDogs()) {
  for (Cat c : p.getCastList()) {

  }

  for (Dog d : p.getDogList()) {

  }
}
```

Comment: I added the mappings. A person does not have knowledge about cats and dogs, so there are no p.catList and p.dogList.

Comment: You should add the mapping between person cat and dog for referential integrity and to make writing queries easier. See my edit.

Comment: Yes, that is the way to do it, but I do not want to use bidirectional relationship and I have to use many to one unidirectional. That is why it is tricky for me.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the [DTO](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) Pattern is used to wrap up the necessary data. Therefore, you can use several object mapping frameworks such as ModelMapper, Modelstruct, Dozer.

If you create two repositories for the cat and dog Entity, you can do the following approach:

Method in CatRepository:

```
List<Cat> findByPersonId(int id);
```

Method in DogRepository:

```
List<Cat> findByPersonId(int id);
```

Querying the persons:

```
List<Person> persons = personRepository.findAll();
List<PersonDto> personsDto = new ArrayList<>();

foreach(Person p:persons) {
   PersonDto dto = modelmapper.map(p, PersonDto.class);
   p.setCats(catRepo.findByPersonId(p.getId()));
   p.setCats(catRepo.findByPersonId(p.getId()));

   personsDto.add(dto);
}
```